# Eliminate effect of VBE in NPN transistor to maintain same gain ratio for a low dc input signal and at all operating voltages

Tags: npn, common-emitter, biasing

Good day,

To monitor the current flowing through a varying resistor load across all supply voltages (8V to 20V DC), I am connecting in series, a small fixed sensing resistor and the drop across this sensing resistor is fed to the NPN transistor circuit for amplification.

The NPN transistor is operated with a gain Vout/Vin = -Rc/Re. Since the input voltage fed to the transistor is a fraction of the supply voltage, ranging from 0V to 2V max, I should be getting a linear amplification of Vout = -Vin*Rc/Rb and in theory I can make a linear function of vout based on supply voltage.

However, due to VBE of 0.7V, this linearity starts only when the Vin exceeds 0.7V and this offset is not desired as (0V to 0.7V) of Vin does not produce a change in Vout.

Is there a possibility of overcoming this problem of VBE? One option that I found in some posts is by using Germanium transistors with VBE of 0.2V but I believe they are pretty much obsolete.

Is there something I am missing or are there any other bright ideas that you could help me with?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You should **forget** about using a single transistor for this. Instead use an **opamp**. Start learning about opamps and how to use them by reading "Opamps for everyone": https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

Answer (score 5):

use a PNP emitter follower to add Vbe to se signal first.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftqBtK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Do you also see the possibility of replacing the PNP transistor by just a diode?

Comment: A diode in series with R_sense could work I guess but it might get hot qnd distort the results, else you're adding current through R1 to current through R_sense.  - there seem to be many  trade-offs to choose between on that path.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you might achieve what you need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuHqEp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This uses Q1 as a summing amplifier, where the summing junction is its base. Negative feedback is provided by R3, which greatly linearises the relationship between the voltage across the sense resistor and the potential at OUT.

There are two inputs to be summed. The first is the regulated +5V provided by zener diode D1, and its influence on \$V_{OUT}\$ is "weighted" by R4. I've chosen R4 here to set \$V_{OUT} \approx +4.5V\$ when there's no voltage across \$R_{SENSE}\$.

The second input is of course the potential \$V_{SENSE}\$ at the top of \$R_{SENSE}\$, weighted by R5.

To retain consistent behaviour across the supply potential range, 8V to 20V, I've had to regulate the voltage provided to the amplifier. That's D1's job, in addition to providing stable biasing for Q1.

Ideally, voltage gain \$A\$ with respect to sense voltage \$V_{SENSE}\$ is:

$$ A = \frac{\Delta V_{OUT}}{\Delta V_{SENSE}} = -\frac{R_3}{R_5} $$

In reality, it will be less, since there is significant base current, and the output impedance is high, at 4.7kΩ, but we can make some approximations.

With the components shown, \$A \approx 10\$, so a rise of 0.1V at SENSE will cause OUT to fall in potential by about 1V. With \$R_{SENSE}=0.5\Omega\$, this corresponds to:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\Delta V_{OUT}}{\Delta I_1 R_{SENSE}} \approx -10 \\ \\
\Delta V_{OUT} \approx -5 \Delta I_1 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

[image]

The graph shows that in reality, transimpedance will be closer to -3.5 volts-per-amp.

Comment: Will this also serve over temperature range? If not, how could it be improved to?

Comment: @TimWilliams I think the low closed-loop gain will mitigate much of the effects of \$V_{BE}\$ vs. temperature. I would expect something like 20mV per K. I don't see an easy way to compensate that. This design cannot compete with a LTP, in this respect, and I wouldn't recommend using it. Still, it addresses the problem that OP asked about.

Comment: @TimWilliams The suggestion by Jasen Слава Україні is far better, and will suffer less from variation of \$V_{BE}\$ vs temperature, but OP *hinted* at wanting to avoid using two transistors. That's what inspired my answer here, otherwise I would have gone the op-amp or LTP route.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a discrete differential pair, with several hundred milliVolts of degeneration voltage drop across emitter resistors.

If you use 1milliAmp of tail current, and 510 ohms resistance in each of the emitters, you will have about a volt of input "linear" range.

Answer (score 0):

> ... are there any other bright ideas that you could help me with?

Yes, there is such a bright idea, and it is called "biasing". Simply put, it means adding that 0.7 V to the input voltage to make the transistor start working from 0 V. But let's start from the beginning with an interesting observation, and step by step reveal the ideas...

## How does supply voltage affect output voltage?

Seen from the collector side, the transistor behaves as a current source. So, if we apply a constant base-emitter voltage to it, the collector current Ic will be constant and accordingly the voltage drop VRc = Ic.Rc across the constant collector resistor will be constant. Figuratively speaking, it acts as a "battery".

### NPN CE stage

Here the positive terminal of the "battery" is connected to Vcc. So, when Vcc varies, the lower negative terminal (the collector) follows its variations... and the whole " battery" moves vith Vcc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFmybp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The conclusion is that, in this configuration, Vout is greatly affected by the supply voltage.

[image: STEP 1.1]

### PNP CE stage

Now the situation is completely different - the negative terminal of the "battery" is connected to ground, and the whole battery is "immovable" . So, when Vee varies, the upper positive "battery terminal" does not move (the collector voltages does not change).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXWVex.png)</sup>

The conclusion is that, in the PNP configuration, Vout does not (well, slightly) change when Vee varies.

[image: STEP 1.2]

## No biasing

Now let's apply this idea to the OP's circuit by flipping it vertically, and investigating it at various loads.

### Rload = 50 Ω

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1OYaB.png)</sup>

### Rload = 100 Ω

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpcOAe.png)</sup>

## Diode biasing

Then let's insert a bias voltages in the input transistor loop thus adding it to Vbe.

### Rload = 100 Ω

Let's first "produce" it by a diode (the OP's idea).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNu3Oj.png)</sup>

### Rload = 1 kΩ

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVdGNw.png)</sup>

## Transistor biasing

Then we can flip likewise the Jasen's circuit.

### Rload = 100 Ω

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fozviU.png)</sup>

### Rload = 1 kΩ

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqiyse.png)</sup>